# android Error parsing data org.json.JSONException

Tags: java, android, json

I have two URLs.

1. https://wimp.supremosolutions.com/api/v1/spot/?format=json
2. https://wimp.supremosolutions.com/api/v1/spot/?format=json&latitude=45.200375&longitude=9.992465000000001

If I run the first one through my android activity then the results load into my List with no problem.
But if I run the second URL then I land up getting this error.

```
05-30 16:20:30.473: ERROR/JSON Parser(1740): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value Invalid of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
05-30 16:20:30.633: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1740): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
        java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.supremosolutions.wimp.AroundMeParking$LoadInbox.doInBackground(AroundMeParking.java:162)
        at com.supremosolutions.wimp.AroundMeParking$LoadInbox.doInBackground(AroundMeParking.java:138)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
        ... 5 more
```

I have run both URLs through json validators like http://jsonlint.com/ and both validate.

The code seems to break on the `jsonParser.makeHttpRequest`:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(callableUrl, "GET", params);
    // Check your log cat for JSON response
    Log.d("JSON FOR LOGCAT: ", json.toString());
```

Sometimes I can see the JSON FOR LOGCAT string in Logcat and it looks like this http://pastebin.com/6CWBAyys (still crashes with that exception though)but sometimes the string doesn't even make it into logcat.

What is the problem here and how can I fix it?

Comment: How is `jsonParser.makeHttpRequest` defined? Please post that code. As a wild guess it returns an `Object`, but under certain circumstances that `Object` is a `String`, perhaps an error message? The exception message `Value Invalid of type java.lang.String` means that the string is `"Invalid"`. Is your URL correct?

Comment: Is-it possible for you to debug the HTTP Request and response. I think that the response is something like `Invalid ...` and so the JSON parser cannot create a JSONObject from it.

Comment: @KenY-N the way in which I was appending parameters in my jsonParser.makeHttpRequest was the problem. I was giving the entire url string with parameters but actually I need to append them with the `params` variable otherwise I get an extra '?' at the end of the URL. This was breaking the app. Please fill out an answer below and I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jsonParser class that I had appends parameters. I was already adding in the base url + the parameters and so the url being sent was invalid.
Instead of sending my URL through like this https://wimp.supremosolutions.com/api/v1/spot/?format=json&latitude=45.200375&longitude=9.992465000000001

I have to send it like https://wimp.supremosolutions.com/api/v1/spot/ but then add NameValuePair parameters to pass into my jsonParser class.

```
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("format", "json"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("format", "json"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("format", "json"));
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL, "GET", params);
```

**As Ken Y-N and Alex mentioned this error is caused by an invalid url. If you get this DOUBLE check how you are creating your URL and see exactly what is being sent**